# Field mapper in X required a bean of type Y that could not be found error happening only when running in VSCode

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, mapstruct

**Error**:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userMapper in com.raven.api.security.jwt.AuthenticationTokenFilter required a bean of type 'com.raven.api.mapper.UserMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.raven.api.mapper.UserMapper' in your configuration.
```

**Mapper**:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface UserMapper {

    UserResponseDto userUserResponseDtoMapper(User user);

    User userRequestDtoUserMapper(UserRequestDto userRequestDto);
    
}
```

**Class which autowires mapper**:

```
public class AuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    
    ...

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }

    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        ...
    }
    
}
```

**The problem**: given error only appears when app is run by VSCode command you can see below (Run -> Run Without Debugging). Using `./gradlew bootRun` no error is present.

**VSCode launch command**:

```
c:; cd 'path\app_name'; ${env:MAIL_USERNAME}='x'; ${env:MAIL_PASSWORD}='x'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_5gfec4y0cg9i694bj8qt8j1f0.argfile' 'com.raven.api.ApiApplication'
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Launch ApiApplication",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.raven.api.ApiApplication",
      "projectName": "api",
      "env": {
        "MAIL_USERNAME": "x",
        "MAIL_PASSWORD": "x"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like VS Code does not properly setup the Gradle defined annotation processors and thus does not see the generated files.

Reading [Is Annotation Processing Supported for Gradle Project in VS Code](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1039) it suggests the use of the [Gradle Eclipse APT](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.diffplug.eclipse.apt) plugin. This is the same plugin that is needed to make annotation processors work in Eclipse.